# Compute Standardized Returns in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to understand how MATLAB works but I end up struggling to implement even the most basic concepts. Let me give you three examples and ask you how to implement them in MATLAB (see attached image). In addition, lets assume that the following table of data holds:

```
1.2; 3.4; 4.6
1.3; 3.7; 4.6
1.0; 3.9; 5.1
1.1; 3.7; 4.6
1.2; 3.8; 4.5
```

In that scenario, i = 1...5 and k = 1...3, and if I understand correctly, we should get something like this:

```
R_hat_1 = (1.2 + 3.4 + 4.6) / 3 = 9.2/3 = 3.067
...
R_hat_5


variance_1 = (1/2) * ((1.2 - 3.067)^2 + (3.4 - 3.067)^2 + (4.6 - 3.067)^2) = 
= (1/2) * (3.48 + 0.11 + 2.35) = (1/2) * 5.94 = 2.97
...
variance_5


Y_11 = (1.2 - 3.067) / 1.72 = -1.08
...
Y_53
```

My question is, how to make it run on MATLAB? What I am missing actually, is how to add and subtract matrices of different dimensions.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

[image: mathematical formulas]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should really take a look at the Matlab documentation as this is fairly basic.

First, you should write the matrix definition as:

```
X = [1.2, 3.4, 4.6; ...
1.3, 3.7, 4.6; ...
1.0, 3.9, 5.1; ...
1.1, 3.7, 4.6; ...
1.2, 3.8, 4.5;];
```

You can then use standard functions to compute the mean and variance:

```
rHat = mean(X,2);

sigma = std(X,0,2); % the 0 is a flag to use N-1 as denominator
var = sigma.^2;
```

And you can work out the final equation thus:

```
Y = (X - repmat(rHat, [1 3])) ./ repmat(sigma, [1 3]);
```